# New ios4 Format not a string literal

Tags: iphone, ios4, warnings

I need to create a string using results of a textfield.

I use :

```
>     NSString *username = [NSString stringWithFormat:myTextField.txt];
```

but i get the warning : 
Format not a string literal and no format arguments.

Everything works but like i use more than 10 times this syntax i would like to erase this warning. 
thanks to all !

Answer (score 3):

In iOS 4 you must do as follows in order to get rid of the warning:

```
NSString *username = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", myTextField.txt];
```

Comment: Warnings aside this is the correct way to use `stringWithFormat`.

Answer (score 2):

That's... not really what `-stringWithFormat:` is for. Use

```
NSString *username = [NSString stringWithString:myTextField.text];
```

or

```
NSString *username = [[myTextField.text copy] autorelease];
```

Comment: myTextField.txt, not .text :)

Comment: I assumed that was a typo—if it's a UITextField, the property is “text”, not “txt”.